# vast / vpaid video can run amp-video ads?

Tags: amp-html, asynchronous-messaging-protocol, iab, vpaid

how can I use the vast / vpaid tag advertisement with the amp-video tag or AMP ads?

I have creted amp story with normal mp4 video by now want to run this with vast Tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html amp4ads>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <script async custom-element="amp-video" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-video-0.1.js">  </script>
  <meta name="amp-cta-url" content="%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%https://www.google.com/">
  <meta name="amp-cta-type" content="EXPLORE">
  <style amp4ads-boilerplate> body { visibility:hidden } </style>
  <style amp-custom>
    amp-video {height:100vh;}
    amp-video video {object-fit: contain}
  </style>
 <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/amp4ads-v0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<amp-video width="720" height="1280" layout="fill" src="720x1280.mp4" poster="" controls autoplay>

</amp-video>
</body>
</html>
```